# How to make container corner round?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make the right upper corner and left upper corner of the white container round, just like below image?

[image]

```
  return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
        Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
            color: Colors.orange),
        Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(40.0)),
              color: Colors.white),
        )
      ]),
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Stack(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(color: Colors.orange),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child:
                Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
              Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                  color: Colors.orange),
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.white),
              )
            ]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `clipBehavior:` on `Container`. Default it is `clipBehavior: Clip.none,`

```dart
Container(
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
   decoration: const BoxDecoration(
```